# The method ambiguous for the type - Why not resolving

Tags: java

```
public class Animal {}

public class Bird extends Animal {}

public class Mamal extends Animal {}

public class Human extends Mamal {}

public class Main {

    public void Hungry(Mamal mamal){
        System.out.println("Mammal");
    }   
    public void Hungry(Human human){
        System.out.println("Human");        
    }
    public void Hungry(Bird bird){
        System.out.println("Bird");
    }
    public static void main(String a[]){
        Main main = new Main();
        main.Hungry(null);
}
```

Compiler says The method Hungry(Mamal) is ambiguous.
I would expect to execute the "Human" method as it is the lowest level. I failed to find the reason for ambiguity from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12

Comment: *" I would expect to execute the "Human" method"* Since when null is a `Human` instance?

Comment: @Sergi: Well conventionally, yes - but it's not part of the rules of the language, which is what this question is about.

Comment: @m0skit0: The `null` literal is convertible to any class type.

Comment: null is not an instance.  it's just a value.

Comment: Please _do not_ capitalize your method's names.

Answer (score 11):

`Human` and `Bird` are at the same level in the inheritance hierarchy (not visually though). Or think of them as completely unrelated reference types. Therefore one isn't more specific than the other.

If you remove the `Hungry(Bird)` method, your code will compile.

The rules for *more specific* are [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5).

> One fixed-arity member method named m is more specific than another
>   member method of the same name and arity if all of the following
>   conditions hold:
>
> - The declared types of the parameters of the first member method are
>     T1, ..., Tn.
> - The declared types of the parameters of the other method are U1, ...,
>     Un.
> - If the second method is generic, then let R1 ... Rp (p ≥ 1) be its
>     type parameters, let Bl be the declared bound of Rl (1 ≤ l ≤ p), let
>     A1 ... Ap be the type arguments inferred (§15.12.2.7) for this
>     invocation under the initial constraints Ti << Ui (1 ≤ i ≤ n), and let
>     Si = Ui[R1=A1,...,Rp=Ap] (1 ≤ i ≤ n).
> - Otherwise, let Si = Ui (1 ≤ i ≤ n).
> - For all j from 1 to n, Tj <: Sj.
> - If the second method is a generic method as described above, then Al
>     <: Bl[R1=A1,...,Rp=Ap] (1 ≤ l ≤ p).

So you have

```
public void Hungry(Human human){
    System.out.println("Human");        
}
public void Hungry(Bird bird){
    System.out.println("Bird");
}
```

So `Human` is `T1` and `Bird` is `U1` (the reverse is also attempted). Methods are not generic.

```
S1 = U1
```

For all `j` from i to n (1 to 1), this should hold: `Ti <: Si`, where `<:` is

> We write T <: S to indicate that that the subtype relation holds between types T and S.

This doesn't hold for our two methods as `Human` is not a sub type of `Bird` and vice versa, so there is no more specific method to call, ie. ambiguity.

It's the same as if you had

```
void method(String s){}
void method(RandomReferenceType t) {}
```

and tried to call

```
method(null);
```

Comment: @TedBigham Human extends Mammal, and is thus considered more specific than Mammal.

Answer (score 2):

Since `null` does not have a type associated with it, the compiler does not know which of your `hungry` methods should be invoked; therefore, it's "ambiguous". To disambiguate it, simply cast it:

```
public class Main {

    public void hungry(Mamal mamal){
        System.out.println("Mammal");
    }   
    public void hungry(Human human){
        System.out.println("Human");        
    }
    public void hungry(Bird bird){
        System.out.println("Bird");
    }
    public static void main(String a[]){
        Main main = new Main();
        main.hungry((Mamal)null);
    }
}

class Animal {}
class Bird extends Animal {}
class Mamal extends Animal {}
class Human extends Mamal {}
```

Answer (score 2):

The amibuity is because you have three methods with same name and you are passing a null value. The compiler doesn't know which method you are calling. Just write one ie `public void hungry(Animal animal)` and check the type of the animal inside. For example `if(animal instanceof Bird) { System.out.println("Bird") ....`.
Also change the method names to lowercase. Sometimes the compiler will fail.